# What is BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID

Tags: java

With the Android-play-location sample I've loaded the sample app but get an unknown member error on `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`.

I can't find anything in your paper that talks about that. Any ideas?

[image: Code]

Comment: I suspect you're trying to talk to the android guys, but you forgot to add the relevant tags

Comment: What do you mean by "in your paper" ?

Comment: Sorry. In the md5 that came with the files from Git